# How can we define a local variable just with its name(with a str)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm working on a pygame game, and I added a "console", and to be able to set a variable with my console. So, when I type the command "set" it's going to take my 2 args: One is the variable name and the other is the value of my variable. But the problem is, I can't find how to set the variable just the name.

Here is an example:

```
self.myVar = "ThisIsMyVar"
self.args = ['var', 'value']
# Here is where I check if the var exist in the code and if it is I want to add the value 
#of self.args[1] to the self.myVar
```

Sorry if I explained it wrong but my English is not perfect,
If you can help me I would be grateful !

Comment: The best course would probably be to have a `dict` holding the configuration (or whatever this is for) and then (a) checking whether `"var"` is a key in that dict (the default value), and (b) setting the value accordingly. You _could_ also use `hasattr`, `getattr` and `setattr`, but then you are opening the doors for players to mess with your game in ways you did not intend.

Comment: If you were using python 2, `eval('var = "value"')` (here some formating may come), but that is no longer available in python 3(.5, I think).

Answer (score 2):

Judging by `self`, these are instance variables, not local variables.

In that case, you're in luck! `setattr` will allow you to set an instance variable's value by name:

```
self.myVar = "ThisIsMyVar"
args = ['var', 'value']
setattr(self, args[0], args[1])
```

Comment: Okay but if my 'var' is like: self.fpsCounter its not working
I want to be able to set any variable juste with his name

Comment: `setattr(self, name, value)` will be able to set any value on `self`. Of course if you immediately reassign the value, e.g. in the next iteration of your game loop, that's another thing.

Comment: This is almost never the correct solution. Yes it literally answers the question the OP has, but this is almost certainly a classic X-Y problem of a beginner not knowing about dictionaries and similar data structures.

Comment: Ok, so i can change know the statue of my variable (its a bool) but my counter is still on the screen and i don't know why ?

Comment: @Lucy That's another question. You'll have to show more of your code - _in another question, not in a comment_ - to solve that.

Comment: @Voo I'd otherwise agree, but OP said they're writing a console for their game, which are usually meant for poking around internals of objects.

Comment: @AKX ok, im just gonna take a break im back in 20min

Comment: @AKX You might be right on that one. Still seems like a dubious architectural decision.

Answer (score 1):

As people have mentioned in comments, a Python dictionary would be a good candidate here.

Python dictionaries are a bit like an indexed list, except that they can be indexed with a string too.

```
console_variables = {}   # empty dictionary to hold console "set" commands
```

So when the user enters the `set` command in the console, e.g.: `set colour red`:

```
set_name, set_value = parseSetCommand( user_input )   # extract set command from input
console_variables[ set_name ] = set_value             # save the setting
```

Later on, any string can be used to find items.  Say you also had a console command of `get`, such that they user could enter `get colour` and expect it to output `red`:

```
get_name = parseGetCommand( user_input )              # extract get command from input
if ( get_name in console_variables.keys() ):          # does this set exist
    consoleWrite( console_variables[ get_name ] )     # Yes: write it back
else:
    consoleWrite( "[" + get_name + "] has not been set" )  # No: error
```

There's some [simple dictionary examples here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm), if you want more examples.  One thing to note is that dictionaries are case-sensitive, so in the above trying to find "Colour" in the dictionary would fail, because it's stored as "colour" (note the capital `C`).  Your code could obviously handle this easily by storing and checking in the same capitalisation-case, maybe everything `.lower()`.